# FlatList doesn't render with React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to rename [0]items in FlatList by clicking some item, But it doesn't work for me, when i click on each item nothing happen and i don't get any error. How can i fix this?

This is my code.

```js
export default function renameSample() {

  const data = [
    {
      id: '1',
      name: 'test1',
    },
    {
      id: '2',
      name: 'test2',
    },
    {
      id: '3',
      name: 'test3',
    },
  ];
  
  const [stateUser, onChangeUser] = useState(data);

  return (
      <FlatList
        data={stateUser}
        renderItem={({item}) =>
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => {
              let setData = stateUser;
              setData[0].name = 'changed';
              onChangeUser(setData);
            }
            }
          >
            <Item name={item.name} />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        }
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Can you share it on snack

Comment: should this be stateUser or selectUser?                                                                                         ```let setData = selectUser;```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your requirement is to change the clicked item, the code would be like below.
You can get the index of the clicked item and change it.

```
function RenameSample() {
  const data = [
    {
      id: '1',
      name: 'test1',
    },
    {
      id: '2',
      name: 'test2',
    },
    {
      id: '3',
      name: 'test3',
    },
  ];

  const [stateUser, onChangeUser] = useState(data);

  return (
    <View>
      <FlatList
        data={stateUser}
        renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => {
             const newData=[...stateUser];
             newData[index].name = 'changed';
             onChangeUser(newData);
            }}>
            <Item name={item.name} />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        )}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Are not you mutating a state directly here?                                                                                                      stateUser[index].name = 'changed';

Comment: Thanks, it’s working!!!!
I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @Zen_Web updated the code, i wasnt sure whether thats a different item selectUser so came up with a code

Comment: I fixed "onChangeUser(setData);" to "onChangeUser([...setData]);", then  it’s working.
Thank you for everyone involved.